# Saving the instance of an Activity to reuse it

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity A with a button on it which when clicked navigates to Activity B. Now from this Activity B when the back button is pressed i get back to Activity A which is quite obvious. But once again when i click on the button on Activity A a new instance of Activity B is launched.

My query: Is there a way so that when i press the back button on Activity B it's instance is stored and so when i again click the button on Activity A the saved instance of B is launched instead of a new one.

Hoping for a solution..

Comment: I agree with barry. Whatever problem you are trying to solve can perhaps be solved better some other way, but you have declined to explain what problem you think you are solving.

Comment: I also agree. If there is data in the instance of ActivityB that needs to be saved/restored, then just put this data in a shared preferences and reload it from there when the new instance of ActivityB is created. There usually isn't a reason to keep around an instance of an Activity just in case the user goes back there.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to pass data.. or just want to go back on Previous activity

```
finish()  in onClick
```

Comment: Infact i want to prevent the finish() to be called in activity B when the Back Button is pressed so that when i relaunch it from Activity A, i get the same instance of B back

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

In addition, the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created.

Comment: thanks for the reply but in the page it is clearly mentioned

"One example of when onPause() and onStop() is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity B to activity A: there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids calling it."

so i suppose onsaveinstance will not provide solution for me :(

Answer (score 0):

To think that it won't be easy to deal with it. The activity in the android can be store but you cannot call the android system to using that instance of your when you navigate to the activity B.

Read this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

it give all information that you can do with it but not all as you want.

When you navigate from activity B to activity A the android itself has been store your activity B's instance temporarily in the memory and that instance will destroy completely anytime later. If you navigate it from A to B again, then the instance of Activity B will be reuse again if it still exist in the memory otherwise it recreate the activity again. In any case the activity B is reuse or recreate, the method onCreate is always call (all method in Lifecycle like onResume ...etc) then all data of your activity B is now new data that's not your old data before you navigate it to the activity A. This is what android system doing so that you cannot launch activity B without calling those method.

if you want the activity B look like the same as before navigate to activity A you should probably saving the necessary data in the method onPause() on the activity B then set those data back to the component of activity B when it call onCreate(). The method  onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) should not be use in this case because the android os version which is before honeycomb (3.0) is not invoked that method.

This could be difficult to deal if you are working with online data or listview, webview ...etc and also save data by your own it could the risk to your application itself.

Anyway I hope this could be some help to you.

Comment: thank you for such an elaborate and detailed explanation. I guess I m asking for a difficult one here :(